# How to implement a Custom dialog box in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and need to create a gallery app that needs a custom dialog box to show the selected image. How can I implement that?

Comment: You need to paste your code what you tried.?
For Starters - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/grid_list_demo.dart

Comment: You can use showDialog widget and show your image in the dialog.

Answer (score 98):

Use Dialog class which is a parent class to AlertDialog class in Flutter. Dialog widget has a argument , "shape" which you can use to shape the Edges of the Dialog box.

Here is a code sample:

```
 Dialog errorDialog = Dialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)), //this right here
  child: Container(
    height: 300.0,
    width: 300.0,
   
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding:  EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Text('Cool', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Text('Awesome', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),
        ),
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0)),
        TextButton(onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
            child: Text('Got It!', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple, fontSize: 18.0),))
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => errorDialog);}
```

Comment: assume that we have custom dialog class and we use it inside another Statefulwidget onTap: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return CustomDialog();
                      });
                }, do we have to pass the context to the customDialog or not. (my thought if the dialog do some change to that statefulwidget  is this going to make the hole widget rebuild again )

Answer (score 69):

#### Screenshot (Null Safe):

[image]

---

#### Code:

Just call this method:

```dart
void showCustomDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierLabel: "Barrier",
    barrierDismissible: true,
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 240,
          child: SizedBox.expand(child: FlutterLogo()),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
        ),
      );
    },
    transitionBuilder: (_, anim, __, child) {
      Tween<Offset> tween;
      if (anim.status == AnimationStatus.reverse) {
        tween = Tween(begin: Offset(-1, 0), end: Offset.zero);
      } else {
        tween = Tween(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset.zero);
      }
  
      return SlideTransition(
        position: tween.animate(anim),
        child: FadeTransition(
          opacity: anim,
          child: child,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 18):

On a button click show dialog as -

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => LogoutOverlay(),
      );
```

Dialog design with two buttons -

```
class LogoutOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => LogoutOverlayState();
    }

    class LogoutOverlayState extends State<LogoutOverlay>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      AnimationController controller;
      Animation<double> scaleAnimation;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        controller =
            AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 450));
        scaleAnimation =
            CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.elasticInOut);

        controller.addListener(() {
          setState(() {});
        });

        controller.forward();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: ScaleTransition(
              scale: scaleAnimation,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  height: 180.0,

                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(41, 167, 77, 10),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0))),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 30.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Are you sure, you want to logout?",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                      )),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: ButtonTheme(
                                height: 35.0,
                                minWidth: 110.0,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                                  splashColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(40),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Logout',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 13.0),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => LoginScreen());
                                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                                    });
                                  },
                                )),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 20.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                            child:  ButtonTheme(
                                height: 35.0,
                                minWidth: 110.0,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                                  splashColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(40),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Cancel',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 13.0),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      /* Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => LoginScreen());
                                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                                   */ });
                                  },
                                ))
                          ),
                        ],
                      ))
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I get the error "The method 'LoginScreen' isn't defined for the class LogoutOverlayState'. … Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'LoginScreen'."

Comment: LoginScreen is a page name where it will redirect on 'Logout' click.

Answer (score 16):

**You just put this class in your project and call its method** for showing dialog.
 Using this class you don't need to write dialog code everywhere

```
class DialogUtils {
  static DialogUtils _instance = new DialogUtils.internal();

  DialogUtils.internal();

  factory DialogUtils() => _instance;

  static void showCustomDialog(BuildContext context,
      {@required String title, 
      String okBtnText = "Ok",
      String cancelBtnText = "Cancel",
      @required Function okBtnFunction}) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(title),
            content: /* Here add your custom widget  */,
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(okBtnText),
                onPressed: okBtnFunction,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text(cancelBtnText),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context))
            ],
          );
        });
  }
 }
```

You can call this method like :

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () =>
              DialogUtils.showCustomDialog(context,
          title: "Gallary",
          okBtnText: "Save",
          cancelBtnText: "Cancel",
          okBtnFunction: () => /* call method in which you have write your logic and save process  */),
      child: Container(),
)
```

Comment: This solution works perfect. Can you elaborate on why using ```.internal```? I would like to understand the background of the internal and factory semantics

Comment: just for create singleton class @JulianOtto

Comment: Why do you need to persist this instance anyway? That's the 100% stateless dialog and there is no need for saving it's the instance, you can go with a simple static method here

Comment: I tried this solution but I got this error
 `Error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.`

Answer (score 13):

1. Alert Dialog
2. Custom Dialog
3. Full-Screen Dialog

ref: [Flutter Alert Dialog to Custom Dialog | by Ishan Fernando | CodeChai | Medium](https://medium.com/codechai/flutter-alert-dialog-to-custom-dialog-966195157da8)

**Alert Dialog**

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Alert Dialog"),
      content: Text("Dialog Content"),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Close"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
        )
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

**Custom Dialog**

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Dialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(20.0)), //this right here
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'What do you want to remember?'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 320.0,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          "Save",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        color: const Color(0xFF1BC0C5),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
```

**Full-Screen Dialog**

```
showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context)
          .modalBarrierDismissLabel,
      barrierColor: Colors.black45,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext,
          Animation animation,
          Animation secondaryAnimation) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 10,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -  80,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Save",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: const Color(0xFF1BC0C5),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
```

Comment: Hi @iHTCboy, I found a mistake not probably but due to updates some features get deprecated in your mentioned code for the Alert Dialog, so I am editing it, even you can also review it once.

Answer (score 6):

I usually build a wrapper for the dialog that matches the app theme and avoids much redundant code.

##### PlaceholderDialog

```dart
class PlaceholderDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlaceholderDialog({
    this.icon,
    this.title,
    this.message,
    this.actions = const [],
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget? icon;
  final String? title;
  final String? message;
  final List<Widget> actions;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      icon: icon,
      title: title == null
          ? null
          : Text(
              title!,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
      titleTextStyle: AppStyle.bodyBlack,
      content: message == null
          ? null
          : Text(
              message!,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
      contentTextStyle: AppStyle.textBlack,
      actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      actionsOverflowButtonSpacing: 8.0,
      actions: actions,
    );
  }
}
```

##### Usage

```dart
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => PlaceholderDialog(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.add_circle,
          color: Colors.teal,
          size: 80.0,
        ),
        title: 'Save Failed',
        message: 'An error occurred when attempt to save the message',
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(ctx).pop(),
            child: Text('!Got It'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

##### Result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An General E.g

```
showDialog(context: context,builder: (context) => _onTapImage(context)); // Call the Dialog.

_onTapImage(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/150',fit: BoxFit.contain,), // Show your Image
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: RaisedButton.icon(
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.close,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              label: Text('Close')),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]**Custom Alert Dialog in Flutter**

```
  void openAlert() {
    dialog = Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0)),
      //this right here
      child: Container(
        height: 350.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/water1.jpg",
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 180,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(16), topRight: Radius.circular(16)),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              decoration: boxDecorationStylealert,
              width: 200,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        showToastMessage("-");
                      },
                      child:Image.asset("assets/images/subtraction.png",width: 30,height: 30,)),
                  Text(
                    "1",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 26,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: black_color),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        showToastMessage("+");
                      },
                      child:Image.asset("assets/images/add.png",width: 30,height: 30,)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Container()),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 6),
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: cancelClick,
                      color: green_color,
                      child: Text(
                        "CANCEL",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: white_color),
                      ),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6, right: 12),
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: okClick,
                      color: green_color,
                      child: Text(
                        "OK",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: white_color),
                      ),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    showDialog(
        context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => dialog);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now use AlertDialog and in content build your widget.

```
showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
   return AlertDialog(
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
     backgroundColor: Colors.green,
     content: Container(
         height:200,
         width:200,
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                          image: FileImage(filepath),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover))),}),
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a working solution in my case:

```
  Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
            Text('Would you like to confirm this message?'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Confirm'),
          onPressed: () {
            print('Confirmed');
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Cancel'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpful:
I've made static function in a separate class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/TGColors.dart';

class TGDialog 
{
  static doNothing() {  }  // stub needed for Function     parameters

/// Returns an AlertDialog with most optional parameters 

 static AlertDialog dlg(  BuildContext context,
                     { String      txtTitle      = 'WHAT? no title?'  ,
                       String      txtMsg        = 'WHAT? no content?',
                       String      txtBtn1       = 'CANCEL'           ,
                       String      txtBtn2       = 'OK'               , 
                       Function    funcBtn1      = doNothing          ,
                       Function    funcBtn2      = doNothing          ,
                       Color       colBackground = TGColors.Orange    ,
                       Color       colText       = TGColors.Indigo     } ) 
 {
  return
    AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor : colBackground,
        title           : Text(txtTitle),
        content         : Text(txtMsg),
        
        actions : <Widget>
        [
          TextButton(
            onPressed : () => { funcBtn1(), Navigator.pop(context,'Cancel')},
            child     : Text(txtBtn1, style: TextStyle(color: colText)),
          ),

          TextButton(
            onPressed :() => { funcBtn2(),Navigator.pop(context)  },
            child     : Text(txtBtn2, style: TextStyle(color: colText)),
          ),
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

An example:

```
Positioned( bottom: 1, left: (screenW / 5.6), 
            child    : FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag  : 'clear',

            onPressed :() => showDialog<String>
            (
              context : context,
             
              builder : (BuildContext context) => 
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                TGDialog.dlg( context, 
                              txtTitle : 'Clear Order?',
                              txtMsg   : 'This resets all item counts' , 
                              funcBtn2 : resetOrder) 
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ),
           
            child     : const Text('clear\nall', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            shape     : RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                        ),
          ),
        ),
```

etc.
Btw: I like CSS webcolors so I defined them in a separate class
like so:

```
import 'dart:ui';
/// Contains mainly web colors  (based on CSS)
/// 
/// Usage e.g:  ... = TGcolors.CornFlowerBlue
class TGColors
{
  static const  PrimaryColor =  Color(0xFF808080);
  static const  AliceBlue =  Color(0xFFF0F8FF);
  static const  AntiqueWhite = Color(0xFFFAEBD7);
  static const  Aqua = Color(0xFF00FFFF);
  static const  Aquamarine = Color(0xFF7FFFD4);  
  // etc.
```

Answer (score -2):

This answer is more to the title of the questions than the details. I.e. "How to build a custom dialog in flutter?"

The main point is to create `CustomDialog` class that returns `AlertDialog`. This way code is cleaner and more readable. Also, `CustomDialog` extends `ConsumerWidget`, hence, providers can be used to get data, and no need to pass data as arguments to constructor:

custom_dialog.dart

```
 class CustomDialog extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final repeatSettings = ref.watch(repeatSettingsProvider);
    int time = repeatSettings.grammaryMinAutoLearningTimeMin!;
    var primaryColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary;
    var secondaryColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;
    var tertiaryColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary;
    return AlertDialog(
      //title: const Text('Засчитать урок?'),

      content: SizedBox(
        height: 100,   //!! applied to content area
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Вы занимались меньше $time минут',
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30, width: 300,
            ),
            Text('Засчитать урок?',
                style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor, fontSize: 18))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        XFlatButton(
          text: 'Да',
          width: 50,
          height: 25,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          bgColor: primaryColor,
        ),
        XFlatButton(
          text: 'Нет',
          width: 55,
          height: 25,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          bgColor: secondaryColor,
        ),
         XFlatButton(
          text: 'Отмена',
          width: 90,
          height: 25,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          bgColor: tertiaryColor,
        ),
        
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Note: `SizedBox` `height` applied to the content area and not the whole widget.

Call it:

```
onPressed: () async {
             
              return _dialogBuilder(context);
            },
...



Future<void> _dialogBuilder(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CustomDialog();
      },
    );
  }
```

And if you like an XFlatButton (otherwise replace it with regular TextButton):

```
class XFlatButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final void Function()? onPressed;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final IconData? iconData;
  final Color bgColor;
  final Color iconColor;
  final TextStyle textStyle;

  const XFlatButton(
      {required this.text,
      this.onPressed,
      this.width = 200,
      this.height = 40,
      super.key,
      this.iconData,
      this.bgColor = Colors.blue,
      this.iconColor = Colors.white,
      this.textStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
        //backgroundColor: bgColor,
        backgroundColor: onPressed == null
            ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer
            : bgColor);
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: TextButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          style: flatButtonStyle,
          //child: Text(text),
          child: iconData == null
              ? Text(
                  text,
                  style: textStyle,
                )
              : Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  Icon(
                    iconData,
                    color: iconColor,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    text,
                    style: textStyle,
                  ),
                ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why downvoted? Too many lines of code? Tired of reading? )))