# Flutter dialog adjust size to content and scroll if content too long

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an AlertDialog (since I was getting worse results with SimpleDialog but that would work as well), that I want to fit the contents within it, which can sometimes be smaller than the available space (and so I want the dialog to shrink to the contents and not have a bunch of empty whitespace) and can sometimes have more content than can fit on the screen (in which case the dialog should expand to fill the available space and be scrollable to see the "overflowing" content).

For the life of me, trying many different combinations of wrapping pieces in various Containers, Expanded, ConstrainedBox, and SizedBoxes, can't get this to work when the content is larger than the available vertical space (it does shrink down correctly). The only way I can get the larger content to properly scroll is if I explicitly set the size to fill the whole screen, which then leaves a bunch of empty white space if the content doesn't fill the size).

Here is a rough example of what I am trying to do (actual code is quite lengthy):

```
AlertDialog(
  content: Container( //or ConstrainedBox
    child: Column(
      children: [
         Container(height: 100),
         Container(height: 100),
         Container(height: 100),
         ListView( //when this doesn't show there, the dialog shrinks properly, when this does show, it overflows and doesn't scroll, 
    //and when wrapped in an expanded to fill the remaining space, there is a Renderflow Viewport error from intrinsic dimensions
           children: [
             Container(height: 500),
             Container(height: 500),
             Container(height: 500),
           ]
         ),
      ]
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610695/7973670
adding SingleChildScrollView will help with the scrolling.

Comment: add shrinkWrap: true to ListView. This tells the Listview to calculate the size of all its children instead of taking as much space as it can. You are getting an error because a Column allows its child to take as much space as it can, making the ListView take infinite space. In the code above, it is better to replace your Column with ListView and remove the nested ListView

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this solution. It works on my emulator.

Basically first, we need a `singlechildscrollview`. Then in listview add below properties

```
 physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
 shrinkWrap: true,
```

Since SingleChildScrollView is scrolling the whole widget, we need to remove scrolling from listview.

Below is the code snippet:

```
onTap: () {
                return showDialog<void>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      content: SizedBox(
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(height: 150),
                              Container(height: 150),
                              Container(height: 150),
                              ListView(
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                children: [
                                  Container(height: 150),
                                  Container(height: 500),
                                  Container(height: 500),
                                  Container(height: 500),
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
```