# custom Alert Dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog

I have to recreate the alert as in the picture, now my problem is that I have to center the various things, as well as insert a textfield and a button. my code written so far is this. it can be done ? I am from swift and am not very familiar with flutter

```
                            onPressed: () => showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text(localization.are_you_sure),
                          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: appColors.green),
                          content: Text(localization.want_to_close),
                        )),
```

[result final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea6fE.png)

Comment: Try using Dialog class instead of AlertDialog. It provides a child paramter where you can add your own custom widget as your dialog box.

Comment: and then I have to create a class on purpose?

Comment: Yes if you will be re using your custom alert box, then it would be better to keep that as a separate widget in a separate class. The AlertDialog and CupertinoAlertDialog also works the same way under the hood. But the have their default themes set based on Cupertino(Apple) and Material(Android) libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a Custom dialog box in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019061/how-to-implement-a-custom-dialog-box-in-flutter)