# Handling firestore permission error and show an alert dialog to the user

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i used a try/catch block but i still get an unhandled exception. i denied a user read and write permission from firestore in order to catch the error that comes with it. the only way i have been able to catch the exception is using  `**.catchError((error) => print("Operation Failed : $error"));**`
Here is my code. i hope i explained well, im new to flutter programming.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:my_time_tracker/app/home/models/job.dart';
import 'package:my_time_tracker/services/api_path.dart';



abstract class Database {
  Future<void> createJob(Job job);
}

class FirestoreDatabase implements Database {
  final String uid;
  FirestoreDatabase({@required this.uid}) : assert(uid != null);

  Future<void> createJob(Job job) async => await _setData(
        path: APIPath.job(uid, 'job_123'),
        data: job.toMap(),
      );

  Future<void> _setData({String path, Map<String, dynamic> data}) async {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    print('$path, $data');
    reference
        .set(data)
        **.catchError((error) => print("Operation Failed : $error"));**
  }
}
```

i already used a try/catch in the _setData method, it didnt work.
i seperated my project so my widget doesnt contain my database logic and now i'm calling the createJob method from my database class in my widget. the error keeps coming from the _setData method in my database

```
    Future<void> _createJob(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final database = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
      await database.createJob(Job(name: 'Cooking', ratePerHour: 35));
    } catch (e) {
      print('failed : $e');
    }
  }
```

This is the error i get when i add the catchError method.

```
I/flutter (17147): /users/u70ZkFMIjUMMEMt5vlIVWhQGbA22/jobs/job_123, {name: Cooking, ratePerHour: 35}
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
W/Firestore(17147): (22.0.1) [WriteStream]: (31ab53e) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
W/Firestore(17147): (22.0.1) [Firestore]: Write failed at users/u70ZkFMIjUMMEMt5vlIVWhQGbA22/jobs/job_123: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
I/flutter (17147): Operation Failed : [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
V/NativeCrypto(17147): Read error: ssl=0x7571676648: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
V/NativeCrypto(17147): Write error: ssl=0x7571676648: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
V/NativeCrypto(17147): SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0x7571676648: I/O error during system call, Success
I/System.out(17147): close [socket][/172.20.10.4:52591]
I/System.out(17147): [socket][8] connection firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.223.234:443;LocalPort=-1(0)
D/        (17147): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.my_time_tracker :443
D/libc-netbsd(17147): getaddrinfo: firestore.googleapis.com get result from proxy gai_error = 7
W/ManagedChannelImpl(17147): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
I/System.out(17147): [socket][9:-1] exception
W/ManagedChannelImpl(17147): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
I/System.out(17147): [socket][9] connection firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.223.234:443;LocalPort=-1(0)
D/        (17147): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.my_time_tracker :443 
I/System.out(17147): [socket][10:-1] exception
W/ManagedChannelImpl(17147): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
D/libc-netbsd(17147): getaddrinfo: firestore.googleapis.com get result from proxy gai_error = 7
W/ManagedChannelImpl(17147): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
I/System.out(17147): [socket][10] connection firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.223.234:443;LocalPort=-1(0)
D/        (17147): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.my_time_tracker :443 
I/System.out(17147): [socket][11:-1] exception
W/ManagedChannelImpl(17147): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
W/ManagedChannelImpl(17147): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
I/System.out(17147): [socket][11] connection firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.223.234:443;LocalPort=-1(0)
D/        (17147): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.my_time_tracker :443 
D/libc-netbsd(17147): getaddrinfo: firestore.googleapis.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/System.out(17147): [socket][12] connection firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.223.234:443;LocalPort=-1(0)
D/        (17147): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.my_time_tracker :443
I/System.out(17147): [socket][/172.20.10.4:52609] connected
I/System.out(17147): [socket][/172.20.10.4:52610] connected
I/System.out(17147): close [socket][/172.20.10.4:52609]

Performing hot reload...                                                
Reloaded 0 of 842 libraries in 546ms.
I/art     (17147): Do partial code cache collection, code=27KB, data=30KB
I/art     (17147): After code cache collection, code=27KB, data=30KB
I/art     (17147): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/flutter (17147): /users/u70ZkFMIjUMMEMt5vlIVWhQGbA22/jobs/job_123, {name: Cooking, ratePerHour: 35}
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
W/Firestore(17147): (22.0.1) [WriteStream]: (31ab53e) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
W/Firestore(17147): (22.0.1) [Firestore]: Write failed at users/u70ZkFMIjUMMEMt5vlIVWhQGbA22/jobs/job_123: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/flutter (17147): Operation Failed : [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
I/System.out(17147): close [socket][/172.20.10.4:52610]
I/System.out(17147): [socket][13] connection firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.223.234:443;LocalPort=-1(0)
D/        (17147): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.my_time_tracker :443
D/libc-netbsd(17147): getaddrinfo: firestore.googleapis.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/System.out(17147): [socket][/172.20.10.4:52635] connected
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
I/System.out(17147): [socket][14] connection firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.223.234:443;LocalPort=-1(0)
D/        (17147): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.my_time_tracker :443 
I/System.out(17147): close [socket][/172.20.10.4:52635]
D/libc-netbsd(17147): getaddrinfo: firestore.googleapis.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/System.out(17147): [socket][/172.20.10.4:52644] connected
I/System.out(17147): close [socket][/172.20.10.4:52644]
I/System.out(17147): [socket][15] connection firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.223.234:443;LocalPort=-1(0)
D/        (17147): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.my_time_tracker :443
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
D/libc-netbsd(17147): getaddrinfo: firestore.googleapis.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/System.out(17147): [socket][/172.20.10.4:52650] connected
I/System.out(17147): close [socket][/172.20.10.4:52650]
I/System.out(17147): [socket][16] connection firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.223.234:443;LocalPort=-1(0)
D/        (17147): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.my_time_tracker :443
D/libc-netbsd(17147): getaddrinfo: firestore.googleapis.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/System.out(17147): [socket][/172.20.10.4:52661] connected
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(17147): endTransaction()
```

if i remove the catchError block and i use a try/catch block i get this unhandled Exception

```
    E/flutter (17147): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.     
E/flutter (17147): #0      MethodChannelDocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:43:7)
E/flutter (17147): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17147): #1      DocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:78:22)
E/flutter (17147): #2      FirestoreDatabase._setData (package:my_time_tracker/services/database.dart:24:17)
E/flutter (17147): #3      FirestoreDatabase.createJob (package:my_time_tracker/services/database.dart:15:50)
E/flutter (17147): #4      JobsPage._createJob (file:///C:/Users/aakanmu/Desktop/my_time_tracker/lib/app/home/jobs_page.dart:35:22)
E/flutter (17147): #5      JobsPage._buildScaffold.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Users/aakanmu/Desktop/my_time_tracker/lib/app/home/jobs_page.dart:75:26)
E/flutter (17147): #6      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
E/flutter (17147): #7      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
E/flutter (17147): #8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
E/flutter (17147): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11)
E/flutter (17147): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
E/flutter (17147): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:222:7)
E/flutter (17147): #12     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:476:9)
E/flutter (17147): #13     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77:12)
E/flutter (17147): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter (17147): #15     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (17147): #16     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter (17147): #17     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter (17147): #18     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:358:19)
E/flutter (17147): #19     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:22)
E/flutter (17147): #20     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:267:11)
E/flutter (17147): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter (17147): #22     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:240:7)
E/flutter (17147): #23     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:213:7)
E/flutter (17147): #24     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (17147): #25     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (17147): #26     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (17147): #27     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
E/flutter (17147): #28     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
E/flutter (17147):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a `catch`, so that's good. All you need to add is a check for the error code of a permission denial, and show an alertdialog in that case:

```
catch(e) {
  if(e.code == "cloud_firestore/permission-denied") {
    showDialog()
  }
  else //more error catching

}
```

Flutter has a [`showDialog` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) that you can use to show one:

```
  showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(message)
      actions: actions,
    );
  });
```

Comment: thanks Amin, my widget and database class are in seperate files. the database class does not have a context for me to pass to the showDialog method. so i want to pass the error to the method calling it from the widget class which is in another file that contains the context i can use to showDialog

Comment: So now you only need to show the dialog?  Have you tried can make your own custom dialog like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53967858/8303912), or using a library like [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get). What have you tried upto now?