# How to create a still pop up menu on top of single child scroll view?

Tags: flutter

How to `popup` a `Container` or make it `visible` on top of a `single child scroll view`? the  scroll view is background, and I want the `popup container` to be still without scrolling on top of the scroll view.

Where should I place the new popup container to be separate it from the scroll view?

**Edit:** I already have created the `container` widget. I just need it to be `shown at a fixed position` in the screen, so it will be on top of the `scroll view`.

[image]

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
   

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
          
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          
          children: <Widget>[
            HomePageWidget(),

]))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

use alert dialog with willpopscope widget in flutter.
The WillPopScope will be triggered when you press back button on the phone.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

  // set up the buttons
  Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("Cancel"),
    onPressed:  () {},
  );
  Widget continueButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("Continue"),
    onPressed:  () {},
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("AlertDialog"),
    content: Text("Would you like to continue learning how to use Flutter alerts?"),
    actions: [
      cancelButton,
      continueButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: (){
        showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
      child : SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
          
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          
          children: <Widget>[
            HomePageWidget(),

]))}}
```

Comment: it should be a Container as I'm trying to make a widget (container) visible, as that container will have other custom buttons or widgets etc.  :)

Comment: @PrettyGirl you can customize the alertdialog as per your need. Use  a column() at content and you can add as many buttons as you like in the actions[] .

Comment: You can refer some examples here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610695/11283638

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try these out, and come back to accept the answer. :)

Comment: it says `Undefined name "context"` in the line of `context: context,`

Answer (score 0):

To showpopups in `Flutter` you need to call `showDialog` with `AlertDialog` like below

```
  showPopup() {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Popup Title : Close App?"),
      content: Text("Please click 'ok' to close the popup"),
      actions: [
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("ok")),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("Close")),
      ],
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ()=>showPopup(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                children: <Widget>[

                  // HomePageWidget(),

                ])),
      ),
    );}
```